# How do I make this code loop permanently like while(true)?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have created a typewriter and it works fine. The only problem is that I can't make the code loop. Is there any easy way to make it? Where is my mistake? I suppose that it doesn't loop because if I make a loop, it is "faster" than the delay in the function.

My code is JavaScript.
I want it to loop permanently, but I also tried a normal for loop and it even then doesn't loop.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
}

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

var i = 0;
var txt = 'welcome to IDM...' + today + "!";
var speed = 50;
var t = true;
var loopTime = 50; // How often in milliseconds the loop should 
//be run
var intervalId = setInterval(typeWriter(), 50);

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;

    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);

  } else {
    k = txt.length;
    (function theLoop(k) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
          txt.substring(0, k);
        if (k--) {
          i--;
          // If i > 0, keep going
          theLoop(k); // Call the loop again, 
          //and pass it the current value of i
        }
      }, 200);
    })(txt.length);
  }

}
```

I need this program to loop permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code inside a large function and then just do:

```
function largeFunction() {
  // Add code here
}

var loopTime = 50; // How often in milliseconds the loop should be run
var intervalId = setInterval(largeFunction, loopTime);
```

Here is a small example of a functioning `setInterval`:

```js
var count = 0;

function largeFunction() {
  document.querySelector("#count").textContent = count++;
}

var loopTime = 1E3;
var intervalId = setInterval(largeFunction, loopTime);
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
```

Also, if you ever want to stop the loop, just call `clearInterval(intervalId);`

I think this is what you were asking for:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
}

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

var txt = 'welcome to IDM...' + today + "!";
var size = 0, mode = 1, speed = 50;
var intervalId = setInterval(loop, speed);

function loop() {
  if (size <= 0) {
    mode = +1;
    size = 0;
  } else if (size >= txt.length - 1) {
    mode = -1;
    size = txt.length - 1;
  }
  size += mode;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt.substring(0, size);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: i've changed my code a bit.
i tried your tipp but it only happens one time :/

Comment: @Vasilis When calling `setInterval`, just pass the function, not the result of the function. Change `setInterval(typeWriter(), 50);` to `setInterval(typeWriter, 50);`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but unfortunately, the solutions don't work. When I pass the function in setInterval it blinks like crazy and doesn't do the right result.

Comment: @Vasilis If its too fast, you just need to increase the loopTime variable

Comment: @Vasilis I updated my answer, just run the last snipet and tell me if it does what it shoud